# Find the next 7 o'clock NSDate

Tags: datetime, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my very specific scenario, I need to get an NSDate holding the next time the hour will be 7 (either AM or PM).

On the case that this is the `first time` to do this, I need to jump extra 12 hours (e.g., if I got Apr 1st 7AM - to jump it to 7PM).

After playing with playgrounds I was able to achieve what I believe solves this, but looking at my code it feels too hard-coded and full of magic numbers. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

```
//constants
NSInteger secInHour = 60 * 60;
NSInteger secInMin = 60;
NSInteger NO_VALUE = NSIntegerMax;

//Break "now" to components
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
cal.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"]; //force a 24hr locale - easier to calculate
NSInteger nowHr = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:date];
NSInteger nowMin = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:date];
NSInteger nowSec = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];
NSTimeInterval nowMS = date.timeIntervalSince1970 - (double)((int)date.timeIntervalSince1970);

//Get closest "7" hour
BOOL isFirstTime = YES;
NSInteger firstTimeDelta = isFirstTime ? 12 : 0;

//find hour distance
NSInteger addHr = NO_VALUE;
BOOL alarmToConcludeDay = true;
if (nowHr >= 7 && nowHr < 19) {
    //now is day
    alarmToConcludeDay = true;
    addHr = 19 - nowHr - 1;
} else {
    //now is night
    alarmToConcludeDay = false;
    if (nowHr < 7) {
        addHr = 7 - nowHr - 1;
    } else {
        addHr = 7 - nowHr - 1 + 24;
    }
}

//sum everything
if (addHr != NO_VALUE) {
    //how much to add to now?
    NSInteger addMin = 60 - nowMin - 1;
    NSInteger addSec = 60 - nowSec - 1;
    NSInteger addMS = 1 - nowMS;

    NSTimeInterval addTotal = (double)((addHr + firstTimeDelta) * secInHour + addMin * secInMin + addSec) + addMS;

    NSDate *alarmDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:addTotal];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a much easier approach to this problem.

We can use `NSCalendar`'s `nextDateAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:` method to find both our next 7am and 7pm.  Then it's simply a matter of comparing these values and returning the lesser of the two.

```
NSDate * nextSevenOClock() {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    components.hour = 7;
    NSDate *nextSevenAm = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date]
                                   matchingComponents:components
                                              options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits];

    components.hour = 19;
    NSDate *nextSevenPm = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date]
                                   matchingComponents:components
                                              options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits];

    NSDate *nextSeven = nextSevenAm;
    if ([nextSeven compare:nextSevenPm] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        nextSeven = nextSevenPm;
    }

    return nextSeven;
}
```

Importantly, this approach with account correctly for things like daylight savings time and leap seconds, which the original solution does not.

---

This method is *very* specific however.  It would be good if we could get a bit more utility out of it.  And rather than a simple C-style function, I've expanded it properly into an `NSDate` category.

```
@implementation NSDate (NextTimeStamp)

+ (instancetype)nextTimeStampMatchingHour:(NSUInteger)hour {
    return [self nextTimeStampMatchingHour:hour minute:0 second:0];
}

+ (instancetype)nextTimeStampMatchingHour:(NSUInteger)hour minute:(NSUInteger)minute {
    return [self nextTimeStampMatchingHour:hour minute:minute second:0];
}

+ (instancetype)nextTimeStampMatchingHour:(NSUInteger)hour minute:(NSUInteger)minute second:(NSUInteger)second {
    NSUInteger morningHour = hour % 12;
    NSUInteger eveningHour = morningHour + 12;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    components.minute = minute;
    components.second = second;

    components.hour = morningHour;
    NSDate *nextAM = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date]
                              matchingComponents:components
                                         options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits];

    components.hour = eveningHour;
    NSDate *nextPM = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date]
                              matchingComponents:components
                                         options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits];

    return [nextAM compare:nextPM] == NSOrderedAscending ? nextAM : nextPM;
}

@end
```

For your original exxample of looking for the next 7 o'Clock, we can just do simply:

```
NSDate *nextSeven = [NSDate nextTimeStampMatchingHour:7];
```

But with these extra methods, we can look for more specific times:

```
NSDate *nextSevenFifteen = [NSDate nextTimeStampMatchingHour:7
                                                      minute:15];
```

Comment: This looks great I will go check it thanks! One thing though: Assuming now its XX:33 and 21 seconds, I don't want the next time it's 7:33:21, but when its 7:00:00, so shouldn't I use `options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime` instead `options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits`?

Comment: It preserves the units from the components, which has 0 for everything less then the hour unit.